# remove specific characters from a string by traversing string only once

Tags: c, string

I was asked this question in an interview but I was not able to answer.
Question was: To remove a specific characters from a given string by traversing string only once.
e.g. Given string is: "aaabbcdabe"
     remove all 'b'
     output: ""aaacdae"

I made this logic but it was traversing string more than once:

```
for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    if(str[i] == 'b')
    {
      for(j=i; str[j]!='\0'; j++)
      {
        str[j] = str[j+1];
      }
    }
}
```

With this logic, string is getting traversed more than once, once in outer for loop and many times in shifting operation.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing recursion..?

Comment: Keep a pointer to the read location and a pointer to the write location. Each time the read-pointer is advanced, only write through the write-pointer if the character is not being removed, then advance the write pointer.

Comment: @DavidBowling sounds good, (anything is better than recursion:).  OP should make sure terminating NUL is written.

Answer (score 5):

Keep a pointer to the read location and a pointer to the write location. Each time the read-pointer is advanced, only write through the write-pointer if the character is not being removed. Advance the write-pointer only when a character is written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_chars(char *str, const char c);

int main(void)
{
    char test_str[] = "aaabbcdabe";

    puts(test_str);
    remove_chars(test_str, 'b');

    puts(test_str);

    return 0;
}

void remove_chars(char *str, const char c)
{
    char *write_ptr = str;

    while (*str) {
        if (*str != c) {
            *write_ptr = *str;
            ++write_ptr;
        }
        ++str;
    }
    *write_ptr = '\0';
}
```

Program output:

```
λ> ./a.out
aaabbcdabe
aaacdae
```

Comment: Have an upboat, if only for the explicit NUL write at the end;)

Comment: This is the best, simplest approach. Though in this case you don't even need `write_ptr`. The pointer to the original string is passed by copy so you can just advance it in place. If the character to be removed is found advance the pointer by 2, otherwise just advance by one.

Comment: @Iguananaut It would be quite impressive if you coded "don't even need write_ptr" or at least another counter.  Looks very difficult to do so using "if the character to be removed is found advance the pointer by 2, otherwise just advance by one." as it lacks any writing.  I look forward to your posted solution.

Comment: No you're right, it's still necessary to at least have a counter of how many items were removed.

Answer (score 3):

This should work. It's pretty short and sweet.

```
int newLen = 0;
int oldLen = strlen(str);
for(int i=0; i<oldLen; i++){
    if(str[i] != 'b'){
        str[newLen] = str[i];
        newLen++;
    }
}
str[newLen] = '\0';
```

Comment: This is essentially the same approach I used in my solution, but with array indexing instead of pointer arithmetic. I think that I prefer the pointer notation in this case, but it is good to see both variations. A couple of notes: you could remove the call to `strlen()` by changing to `for(int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {}`; also, it is best to use `size_t` for array indices, as this is an `unsigned` integer type guaranteed to be able to hold any array index, and is the correct type for array indices. +1